# Solve the equation in php

Tags: php, math

How to solve this equation in php:

```
Ym = Zm * Zm+1 * Zm+2...Zm+n
```

Where,

```
Y = Unknown
m = array if numbers (1,2,3,4...)
z = array of numbers (8,6,9,10...). Number of elements of "Z" and "Y" array dependent from array "m".
```

**For instance:**

```
m = (1,2,3,4);
z = (5,6,10,7);
Y1=5*6*10*7
Y2=6*10*7
Y3=10*7
Y4=7
```

This equation was written by me. I think I've done something wrong while writing equation (Ym = Zm * Zm+1 * Zm+2...Zm+n). What I need is the example above.

Thanks!

Comment: See http://www.phpclasses.org/package/8125-PHP-Solve-linear-polynomial-trigonometric-equations.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something in the lines of:

```
$m = array(0, 1, 2, 3);
$z = array(5, 6, 10, 7);
$Y = array(1, 1, 1, 1);
for ($x=0; $x<count($m); $x++) {
  for ($w=$x; $w<count($m); $w++) {

    $Y[$m[$x]]=$Y[$m[$x]]*$z[$w];
  } 
  print "Y[{$m[$x]}]={$Y[$m[$x]]}\n\r";
}
```

Example http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/063e363111f4da275475c9c39dd8e7281083d22b

In functional programming language like Mathematia aka Wolfram language this would just be:

```
Y=FoldList[Times,1,{5,6,10,7}]
```

Comment: Margus, unfortunately it's incorrect. I got sth like this: Undefined offset AND Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 )